# Create a favorite list in Ionic Framework

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angular-local-storage

I am very new to Ionic Framework. I am learning the framework and have tried to build a simple android app, which displays a simple list using json. Now, I want add a favorite list which will show user selected items in it. When user clicks on a button it should add that item in a favorite list. And When user click on Favorite tab it should show list of all favorite items.
At present I am trying to do this with simple json and global controller. But I am afraid if this is used on android app on a phone it will not store all favorites, it would remove all favourites once app is closed. Can anyone please suggest a better approach towards it.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I see you tagged the question with local storage, so why not use that? Also, you could use one of the popular mBaaS solutions like [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) or [gunDB](http://gun.js.org/).

As for the logic, it's quite easy: you create a new array which you use for storing these favorites (you handle the adding/removing on the favorite button click). You then use the ng-repeat on the Favorites tab to list the favorites array.

Comment: I was doubtful on localstorage thing.. I am from UI background so not used to DB stuff.. can you please put more light on this.. how these are useful with Ionic Framework

Comment: Well, they're useful in a way that they let you "persist" data - in more practical terms - your favorite list won't "disappear" once you exit the app and load it again. You may want to check this official ionic tutorial: http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/localstorage/ or this one http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-lokijs-for-local-storage-in-your-ionic-app/ to get a bit more know-how.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be [pouchdb](http://pouchdb.com/), i m using in same way.!

Install pouchdb using command:

```
bower install pouchdb
```

add below line in index.html

```
<script src="lib/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
```

make a service:

```
.factory('FavService', function (UserService) {
    var FavService = {};
    var localDB;
    var user = UserService.getUser();


    if (user) {
        localDB = new PouchDB('u_' + user.id);
    }

    FavService.configDbs = function () {
        //console.log('config dbs');
        var user = UserService.getUser();
        if (user) {
            localDB = new PouchDB('u_' + user.id);
        }
    };

    FavService.storeToLocal = function (product) { //change function name
        if (localDB && product !== "") {
            localDB.post(product);
            // console.log("Action completed");
        } else {
            // console.log("Action not completed");
        }
    };

    FavService.getLocalList = function (callback) {
        if (localDB) {
            localDB.allDocs({
                include_docs: true
            }).then(function (response) {
                // console.log("response :"+JSON.stringify(response));
                localDB = response.rows;
                callback(response.rows);
            }).catch(function () {
                callback(null);
            });
        } else {
            FavService.configDbs();
        }
    };
});
```